# gsub() in R is not replacing '.' (dot)

Tags: r, regex, gsub, stringr

I want to replace dots in `"2014.06.09"` to `"2014-06-09"`. I am using *gsub()* function for it. If

```
x <-  "2014.06.09"
gsub('2', '-' ,x)
# [1] "-014.06.09"
```

But when I try

```
gsub('.', '-', x)
# [1] "----------"
```

instead of `"2014-06-09"`.

```
class(x)
# "character"
```

Can some suggest me a way to get this right and also why it is not working for `'.'` (dot)

Answer (score 174, accepted):

You may need to escape the `.` which is a special character that means "any character" (from @Mr Flick's comment)

```
 gsub('\\.', '-', x)
 #[1] "2014-06-09"
```

Or

```
gsub('[.]', '-', x)
#[1] "2014-06-09"
```

Or as @Moix mentioned in the comments, we can also use `fixed=TRUE` instead of escaping the characters.

```
 gsub(".", "-", x, fixed = TRUE)
```

Comment: @drmariod Yes, that is an alternative

Comment: Or use `fixed = TRUE` which doesn't use regex but instead just searches for the characters. `gsub(".", "-", x, fixed = T)`

Comment: what if we want to change every single punctuation signs with something else like space? In dealing with texts from social media or reviews I come up with a lot of dots or other punctuation signs between words, because the forgot to use space after they finish the sentence.

Comment: @MehdiAbbassi You can do `gsub("[[:punct:]]", " ", x)`

Answer (score 6):

For more complex tasks the stringr package could be interesting

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/stringr.html

https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/strings.pdf

```
library(stringr)

str_replace_all(x,"\\.","-")
## [1] "2014-06-09"
```

Or

```
str_replace_all(x,"[.]","-")
## [1] "2014-06-09"
```

Answer (score 5):

Using raw strings, introduced in R 4.0.0, one could do

```r
gsub(r"(\.)", "-", x)
# [1] "2014-06-09"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `chatrtr`

```
x <-  "2014.06.09"
chartr(".", "-", x)
## [1] "2014-06-09"
```

Also if the reason to do this is to convert it to Date class we can avoid the substitution entirely using any of these

```
as.Date(x, "%Y.%m.%d")
## [1] "2014-06-09"

library(lubridate)
ymd(x)
## [1] "2014-06-09"
```